# how to put a value into a variable onclick?

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP (so no bullying) and I'm trying to insert a row into my database on click without reloading (or with reloading if it is too complicated not to).
Basically, if you go to http://akas.imdb.com/title/tt0212671/ and click on "Add to Watchlist", the code adds the movie_id to your user_id (via some joint table). How do I do that ?

I don't understand how I can trigger the action or how I would put my two values to be inserted into a variable without reloading ?

Sorry if this doesn't make any sense, it's pretty hard to explain.

Thanks

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<h1><a href="tvshow.php?show=' . $row[1] .  '">' . $row[1] . $row[0].'</a></h1>';
};

$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```

When someone click on "Add to watchlist", I want to insert into a joint table $row[0] and $id

Comment: If you are trying to learn PHP, you should learn the right way and NOT use `mysql_*` functions.  These are deprecated and should no longer be used.  Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: You need to read about AJAX and Javascript.

Comment: What you're trying to do is a mix of different technologies. PHP, sure. You also need your script(s) to connect to the database, and you should be reading on javascript / ajax which you will need to send the request to your server without doing the page reload. Then handle the response of your server in javascript and do what you need to do to your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this without page reload, you need two things.  First you need a script available on an endpoint on your server to do the database insert.  Second, you need a javascript AJAX call to call this script, passing it the necessary data for insert.

You should research AJAX to understand how it works, as this is a fundamental part of modern web applications.

Comment: Thanks.Anybody coming accross this thread, there seems to be a decent tutorial there: http://www.webstutorial.com/insert-record-into-database-using-ajax-how-to-insert-data-into-database-using-ajax/ajax

Answer (score 0):

you have to use AJAX for that, to call a php page that will do the insert and output what you want, after this you will be able to set a variable on the ajax Success method.

php is not client side language, you cant do anything with php after the page is loaded, only AJAX